# Reading output of QNEAT3 plugin in R

Tags: qgis, r

If I create Iso-Area polygons using QNEAT3 plugin in QGIS, is it possible to get an output and read it in R for doing further data analysis? If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: I have no knowledge of R packages for reading geospatial data - but the Iso-Area polygons can be written to any standardized vector data format so it should be fairly easy to add the result dataset in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save a QGIS layer in a format suitable for reading into R, right-click on the polygon layer and choose "Export..." "Save Features as...", or with the Layer selected in the Layers dialog, choose "Layer" "Save As..." from the menu.

Change the format to GeoPackage, choose a file name and a layer name (a single GeoPackage can contain multiple layers) and hit "Ok".

You can read them into R with the `sf` package function `polygons <- st_read(geopackage, layer)`